# Continuous Pipe Input

Tags: c, bash, shell

I am looking for a method of piping input from one program into another continuously. Can iNotify or file polling be used on `stdin` or am I better off using a temp file.

Edit

Sorry for not indicating that it was in reference to a shell pipe NOT a Pipe(2).

Comment: Are you talking about pipe(2)?

Comment: What's wrong with `./prog2 < file1`?

Comment: @KerrekSB thats **NOT**  Pipe, thats shell redirection

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: OK, sure, but if it solves the problem, why not? (And it should be `./prog2 <(./prog1)` I suppose.)

Comment: Note that shells use the `pipe(2)` to create pipes on all Unix-like machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipes already operate continuously. If you run `prog1 | prog2`, every time `prog1` writes more output to stdout, `prog2` will see this on stdin and be able to read it. `prog2` won't see an end of file on the pipe until `prog1` closes its side of the pipe (or exits, which does the same thing).

Comment: This is typically sound and standard practice, but note that it is quite possible for `prog1` to terminate and not close the pipe.  For example, if `prog1` is `sh -c 'yes&'`, then it will terminate but will have spawned the child process running `yes` which keeps the pipe open.  It is easy to see more pathological cases.

Comment: @WilliamPursell This is true, but a bit beside the point. I wanted to demonstrate that the pipe would stay open as long a prog1 kept it open. There are obviously a lot more details and corner cases to describe the behavior of pipes in general, but for the basic use case described in the question, a simple pipe suffices.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for the notification, I would not have considered the status of the pipe if `prog1` had been terminated. Are there any standards or coding practices I can use for checking the status of that pipe. Since it isn't forked I can't think of any ways to check the status of either program.

Comment: @Blackninja543 I'm not sure I exactly understand your question.  `if prog1 | prog2; then` is the standard way to check the exit status of the pipe (which is the status of `prog2`).  Note that the caveat I mention in my first comment really is not something to worry about, as it's a fairly uncommon problem.